# Error MySQL caracteres inválidos?

Tags: mysql

Estou usando esta query para fazer uma busca no banco:

```
SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE cidade LIKE ? LIMIT 1
```

no placeholder eu usei "Nárnia"

E recebi este erro:

```
General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like' trace
```

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

O operador `LIKE` precisa de outras informações - chamados de *wildcards* - no seu *placeholder* para entender o que deve fazer, como o `%`.

Então, tente algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE cidade LIKE '%Nárnia%' LIMIT 1
```

Não sei qual tecnologia está usando para substituir o *placeholder* então deve ser algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE cidade LIKE '%?%' LIMIT 1
```

Comente aqui o jeito certo de fazer, e me diga a tecnologia que está usando, por favor.

Comment: Irei, testar, estou usando PHP, com o ORM RedBean, obrigado pela resposta.